# Qt Moc generates code with undefined behaviour

Tags: qt, c++11, clang++

I have a simple class which has a QT signal that gives me trouble when compiling the moc generated code. I don't use the qmake buildsystem, but my scons build script calls qt' moc command directly.

The relevant source file **"write_qstring.h"** is:

```
#ifndef LOG_WRITE_QSTRING_POLICY_H
#define LOG_WRITE_QSTRING_POLICY_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QString>

namespace Log
{
class WriteQString : public QObject
    {
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
    signals:
    void Changed(QString newString);
    };

}

#endif // LOG_WRITE_QSTRING_POLICY_H
```

I run the moc compiler with the command:

> /opt/Qt/5.2.0/gcc_64/bin/moc -DQT_CORE_LIB
>   -I/opt/Qt/5.2.0/gcc_64/include/QtCore -I/opt/Qt/5.2.0/gcc_64/include -o moc_write_qstring.cc write_qstring.h

and then I compile the generated moc_write_qstring.cc using clang++:

> clang++ -o moc_write_qstring.o -c -Weverything -pedantic -g -std=c++11
>   -fcxx-exceptions -pthread -fdiagnostics-fixit-info -fPIC -Wno-c++98-compat -Wno-documentation-unknown-command -Wno-documentation -Wno-padded -Wno-weak-vtables -Wno-exit-time-destructors -Wno-global-constructors -isystem/opt/Qt/5.2.0/gcc_64/include -isystem/opt/Qt/5.2.0/gcc_64/include/QtCore -DQT_CORE_LIB -I/opt/Qt/5.2.0/gcc_64/include/QtCore moc_write_qstring.cc

This gives a warning about undefined behaviour:

> warning: dereference of type '_t *' (aka 'void
>   (Log::WriteQString::**)(QString)') that was reinterpret_cast from type
>   'void **' has undefined behavior [-Wundefined-reinterpret-cast]
>   With the relevant line being:
>   if (*reinterpret_cast<_t *>(func) ==
>   static_cast<_t>(&WriteQString::Changed)) {

Since the compiler is warning about undefined behaviour I can only think the code is broken, but why is the metacompiler emitting broken code? **What did I do wrong here? is it a c++11 problem??**

Output of clang++ --version

> Ubuntu clang version 3.5-1~exp1 (trunk) (based on LLVM 3.5) Target:
>   x86_64-pc-linux-gnu Thread model: posix

Output of qmake --version

> QMake version 3.0 Using Qt version 5.2.0 in /opt/Qt/5.2.0/gcc_64/lib

Comment: I guess it only means that the standard does not define what must happen; it also means that gcc is free to do whatever it wants to do. If gcc does the Right Thing, that's OK by the standard. I don't think anything is broken here. You can do very little in strictly standard C++ compared to non-standard C++. You are forced to do non-standard things if you wish to do GUI programming for example.

Comment: The code is not broken. Remember that Qt is supported on a finite number of platforms. On those platforms, it's supposed to work. On others, caveat emptor. In spite of the warning, the code works. This is so fundamental that literally nothing in Qt would work if this generated code was wrong. If it didn't work, Qt Creator wouldn't work either :)